# When I generate my website the render is different than in my dev environment (using Nuxt with Vuetify)

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have an issue with Vuetify using Nuxt. When I generate my website the font size is bigger than in my dev environment and my own `<style>` is missing... For example, I have forced the text to be in lower case but it isn't in my `dist` folder. Do you know where this comes from?

I have tried to fix this by manually import Roboto font by doing this:

```
//nuxt.config.js

export default {

  head: {
    link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900'}
    ]
  },
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I just added `!important` for my own `<style>` and that solves the issue for text style!
But there still the issue with the size of the font... If someone could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find where this comes from

The font was forced to be 20px in the `~/assests/variables.scss` I just had to remove this line `$font-size-root: 20px;`. By exploring my commit, it where added when I upgrade Vuetify from 1.5 to 2.0.

I don't remove this question if someone has the same issue one day.